# Open source Libraries for Animating thumbnail to full size screen similar to Facebook

Tags: java, android, android-animation, android-gallery, photo-gallery

Wanted to know if there are any open source libraries available for Android similar to [IDMPhotoBrowser](https://github.com/ideaismobile/IDMPhotoBrowser) available for iOS. This library is very good and offers features like zoom in from original image to full view (animating thumbnail to full size screen), swipe to dismiss image etc similar to Facebook. I want to implement similar features for Android and so are there any libraries for Android that provide these features and are also easy to customize?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PhotoView](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView) is the library by *Chris Banes* which is Implementation of ImageView for Android that supports zooming, by various touch gestures.

Also, Facebook's Image Management Library [Fresco](http://frescolib.org/) has a `SimpleDraweeView` (Customized Image View) that supports [ZoomableDraweeView](https://github.com/facebook/fresco/blob/master/samples/zoomable/src/main/java/com/facebook/samples/zoomable/ZoomableDraweeView.java) with [sample code](https://github.com/kunny/ZoomableDraweeView-sample).

But Using Fresco for this small zoom effect will cost time.

Comment: Thanks @vipul_asri, But I wanted to achieve effect similar to http://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom.html by using open source library if available.